# Upgrading to Neo4j 2.2.5 and Spring Data 4.0.0.RELEASE - embedded database neo4jServer

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to upgrade my application to Neo4j 2.2.5 and Spring Data 4.0.0.RELEASE

With new Neo4jConfiguration I need to override `neo4jServer` method:

```
@Override
public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

How to implement this method in order to use Neo4j embedded database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Data for Neo4j 4.0 doesn't support Embedded mode.

Version 4.1 should support Embedded mode.

Comment: Is it only related to SDN 4.0 or to Neo4j also ? Should I continue use Neo4j embedded mode or this mode will be removed from Neo4j ?

Comment: Now it's related to SDN 4.0. Neo4j still support embedded mode.

Comment: It's planned for 4.1 though

Comment: Does 'Spring Data for Neo4j 4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT' support embedded mode?